# Convert Terraform reference output type in cdktf

Tags: terraform, terraform-cdk, cdktf

I have two resources in TF that I linked.

```py
        service_account = \
            ServiceAccount(tf_stack,
                           id='123',
                           description='',
                           name="service-account",
                           provider=cc_provider)

        api_key = ApiKey(tf_stack,
                         id='api-keys',
                         environment_id="env-xxxxx",
                         cluster_id="lkc-123123",
                         user_id=service_account.id,
                         provider=cc_provider)
```

The `ServiceAccount.id` is a `string`, but `ApiKey.user_id` is `int`.
When running this I get a legit exception from `cdktf` for type mismatch when setting `user_id` on `ApiKey` object.

Is it possible to craft type conversion of those variables somehow?
In plain TF it's not a problem as I'd use `atoi` for this.
But my challenge to make it work with `cdktf`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```py
        api_key = ApiKey(tf_stack,
                         id='api-keys',
                         environment_id="env-xxxxx",
                         cluster_id="lkc-123123",
                         user_id= "atoi(" + service_account.id + ")",
                         provider=cc_provider)
```

this would render the terraform file with `atoi` function and then it should work as it works with normal terraform.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, as `user_id` can only accept `Union[int, float, None]`
meaning this object creation will fail, as the class validates type correctness

Comment: Oh okay, did you find any other workaround???

Answer (score 0):

Terraform CDK introduced Terraform Functions in 0.7, so you should be able to use `Fn.tonumber` now:

```
    service_account = \
        ServiceAccount(tf_stack,
                       id='123',
                       description='',
                       name="service-account",
                       provider=cc_provider)

    api_key = ApiKey(tf_stack,
                     id='api-keys',
                     environment_id="env-xxxxx",
                     cluster_id="lkc-123123",
                     user_id=Fn.tonumber(service_account.id),
                     provider=cc_provider)
```